# How to return a variable from ananymous inner class located inside a method

Tags: java

I want to return a string from anonymous class which is specified inside a method.Here i want to return respMessage  from the method parseXml. I am not sure how to do this , I cannot make it as a class variable . Please let me know how to return this ? I also cannot make it final because local final variable has to be assigned and cannot be reassigned.

```
private String parseXml(String resXml) {
    logger.info("In sax parsing");
    //final String respMessage;

    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {

            boolean isResMessage = false;
            protected String respMessage;

            public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

                if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("ErrorMessage")) {

                    isResMessage = true;
                }
            }

            public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) throws SAXException {

                if (isResMessage) {

                    respMessage = new String(ch, start, length);

                    isResMessage = false;
                }
            }

            public String getRespMessage() {
                return this.respMessage;
            }
        };

        saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(resXml)), handler);

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return this.DefaultHandler().getRespMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In anonymous classes, you can't use non-final local variables from the enclosing method. But there is a well-known trick: use a final array of one element, and your anonymous class can modify the element:

```
    try {

        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
        final String[] result = new String[1];

        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            void someMethod() {
                result[0] = ...;
            }
            ...
        };
        ...
        return result[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create a proper class, or at least define a [local class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html):

```
try {
    ...
    class Handler extends DefaultHandler {
        ...
    }

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(resXml)), handler);
    return handler.getRespMessage();
} catch (Exception e) {
    ...
    return null;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a mutable reference outside your class, for example `StringBuilder`:

```
private String parseXml(String resXml) {
    final StringBuilder respMessage = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        ...
        DefaultHandler handler = new DefaultHandler() {
            ...
            respMessage.append(new String(ch, start, length);
            ...
        }
        saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(resXml)), handler);
    }
    ...
    return respMessage.toString();
}
```

Finally, the hackiest solution is to call the `parse()` method in the initializer and return the result in the same expression:

```
return new DefaultHandler() {
    {
        saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(resXml)), this);
    }
    ...
}.getRespMessage();
```